# Paging request sent to wrong route in Rails 3.2 app search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

When performing search on `engine_config` table, the first page of the search result is properly displayed. However when clicking 2nd page on the search output page, there is an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OnboardDataUploadx::EngineConfigsController#show

Couldn't find OnboardDataUploadx::EngineConfig with id=search_results
```

Here is the error on `rails server` output:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/onboard_data_upload/engine_configs/search_results"):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  ........
```

It seems that the controller routes to the action `show` to display the 2nd page. The controller should route to `#search_results` instead of `#show` and we don't why the controller does that.

Here is our routes definition in routes.rb:

```
resources :engine_configs do
    collection do
      get :search
      put :search_results  
    end
end
```

In the engine configs' controller, the action `search` and `search_results` are defined as:

```
def search #display the page to set search parameters
  @model, @search_stat = search_(params)
  @results_url = 'search_results_engine_configs_path'
end

def search_results  #come out with search results set above
  @s_s_results_details =  search_results_(params, @max_pagination)
end
```

The search results is stored in `@s_s_results_details.models` which add pagination with `models.page(params[:page]).per_page(max_pagination)`. Gem will_paginate 3.0.4 is used in the app.

What could be wrong with the search code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your route for search_results to get.

`resources :engine_configs do
    collection do
      get :search
      put :search_results
    end
 end`

Becomes:

`resources :engine_configs do
    collection do
      get :search
      get :search_results
    end
 end`

You only need to use put if the HTTP request will be modifying database records.

Comment: drummondj, you are right. Also changed :method => :put to :method => :get in search view. Otherwise it throws out route for (search results) can not be found error. Many Thanks!